# Get channel thumbnail image using videos list endpoint

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way to get the profile (thumbnail) images of all the channels that are returned with the video list endpoint in the youtube api?

All I get using this endpoint is the channel name and ID and then I have to make a second API call to the channels list endpoint with all the channel ID's (which is then returned unordered). This takes forever.

Comment: What's available that you can do is make calls to [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and use the "snippet" parameter because it contains the thumbnail property - "snippet.thumbnails - A map of thumbnail images associated with the video. For each object in the map, the key is the name of the thumbnail image, and the value is an object that contains other information about the thumbnail."

Comment: Hey @noogui thanks for your response. I know and I'm already retrieving the thumbnails of the videos but I would also like to additionally retrieve the "profile image" of each channel associated with the videos in the list. And as far as I can tell, that's only possible by doing a second API call to the channels endpoint...

Comment: yeh? what property is that? I only saw snippet.thumbnail no snippet.profile

Comment: yea that's exactly my problem, it's not in snippet of Videos.list, but in snippet of Channels.list: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Comment: Well all the properties for Channels is in [Channel Resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource) - if it's not there, it's not supported.

Comment: @noogui ,Sending a separate request for every channel image is the  problem here. Channel image should be received in the same request of the video endpoint to save resources and make less requests.

Comment: hi there, could you resolve this?